# Unchecked checkbox sending value as true

Tags: php, html, forms

Why is the server getting bool true when the checkbox isn't checked? I did a variable dump because it was sending email to all the emails when the checkbox was not even checked. Below is my PHP  and below that one is the html form

```php
    <?php
    $fname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['fname']);
 $lname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['lname']);
 $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
 $cell = htmlspecialchars($_POST['cell']);
 

//Form Items
$ferventfoodies = htmlspecialchars($_POST['ferventfoodies']);
$whatsnext = htmlspecialchars($_POST['whatsnext']);
$youngcouplesmentorship = htmlspecialchars($_POST['youngcouplesmentorship']);
$itsnotaboutme = htmlspecialchars($_POST['itsnotaboutme']);
$wedensdaynightbiblestudy = htmlspecialchars($_POST['wedensdaynightbiblestudy']);
$theconversation = htmlspecialchars($_POST['theconversation']);
    

var_dump(isset($ferventfoodies));
var_dump(isset($whatsnext));
var_dump(isset($youngcouplesmentorship));
var_dump(isset($itsnotaboutme));
var_dump(isset($wedensdaynightbiblestudy));
var_dump(isset($theconversation));
    ?>
```

Form

```html
<form action="https://1moment.today/gg-submission.php" method="post">

 <input type="checkbox" id="ferventfoodies" name="ferventfoodies">
<label for="ferventfoodies"></label>

 <input type="checkbox" id="whatsnext" name="whatsnext" >
<label for="whatsnext"></label>
                    
<input type="checkbox" id="youngcouplesmentorship" name="youngcouplesmentorship"> 
<label for="youngcouplesmentorship"></label>

 <input type="checkbox" id="theconversation" name="theconversation">
<label for="theconversation"></label>

<input type="checkbox" id="itsnotaboutme" name="itsnotaboutme">
<label for="itsnotaboutme"></label>


<input type="checkbox" id="wedensdaynightbiblestudy" name="wedensdaynightbiblestudy">
<label class="overflow" for="wedensdaynightbiblestudy">
        </label>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: The links you posted are not right.

Comment: hi, links that you have given are generating 404 error... moreover paste your code here directly in question...

Comment: Post your (**minimal**) code here, not on an external site. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @KhangTran code is below the question

Comment: @Don'tPanic TY! code is below the question

Comment: @AnantV thanks! the code is below the question

Answer (score 1):

You've misdiagnosed the problem.

The checkbox will either send `On` or *nothing* depending of it is checked or not. For the rest of this question I will assume it is unchecked and sending nothing.

---

> ```
> $ferventfoodies = htmlspecialchars($_POST['ferventfoodies']);
> ```

This will output **two** warnings:

> PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "ferventfoodies"

and

> Deprecated: htmlspecialchars(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated

It will then assign `""` to `$ferventfoodies`.

Make sure you have PHP configured, in  your development environment, to [show you all your warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) because they are telling you what your real problem is.

---

> ```
>  var_dump(isset($ferventfoodies));
> ```

Now **this** will output `true` because you set `$ferventfoodies` to an empty string.

---

To fix this:

- Refactor your code to apply the `isset` check **directly** to `$_POST['ferventfoodies']`
- Only use `htmlspecialchars`:

  - on **strings** (i.e. not on `null`)
  - on data you are outputting to HTML (i.e. not on data you are testing for specific values / inserting into a database / anything except being inserted into HTML).